# Present participle or adjective in this sentence?

Tags: tense

It's from Charlotte's Web by E.B. White.

> The grass was wet and the earth smelled of springtime.
>   Fern's sneakers were sopping by the time she caught
>   up with her father.

Why author used 'were sopping'? Is 'sopping' a present participle or an adjective in the sentence? And is it correct to say:

> Fern's sneakers had sopped by the time she caught
>   up with her father.

Comment: It means "Fern's sneakers were sopping (wet)..." The book uses literary but (in my experience) not regular usage of the verb [*sop*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sop).

Comment: But the state had changed 'by the time' so I'm confused with using 'by the time' because it sounds like finished action.

Comment: The word *sopping* is being used as an adjective to mean "soaked through." As in, her sneakers became soaked through prior to catching up to her father, so they *were sopping* by the time she did catch up. Your other sentence doesn't sound right to me, but I'd probably know what you meant. I couldn't say whether it's wrong or just unusual.

Comment: godel9, thanks. And how can I use perfect tenses to say correctly?

Comment: @user3169 - [_sopping_](http://wordnik.com/words/sopping) is also an adjective meaning soaking wet. I think that’s what’s going on here.

Comment: "Sopping" is an adjective, not a participle. There is a verb 'sop', but it has a different meaning. Your first example is fine -  "sopping" is modifying "wet". Your second example is ungrammatical since for this meaning "sopped" is not a past participle and hence cannot occur in a perfect tense verb phrase.

Answer (score 1):

There is a verb "[to sop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sop#Verb)". It means to dip into a liquid.

> He sopped his bread in the gravy.

It's pretty rare now, almost completely replace by "dunk", The phrasal verb "sop up" is only a little more common.

So pragmatically, can we believe that The sneakers were dipping (something) into a liquid?  Ridiculous! This is *not* the present continuous form of the verb "sop".

But there is an [adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sopping#Adjective) "sopping" which means very wet (obviously a related word) It must be the adjective that is intended here. You will also see the phrase "sopping wet" used as an adjective