# Difference between “I’m sulking” and “I’m sulky”

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

What's the difference between saying:

> 1. I'm sulking

> 2. I'm sulky

Comment: 1) At the moment, and 2) all of the time.

Comment: and what about he's being sulky?

Comment: At the moment. The same as "he is sulking." But the question needs more context. English is rather slippery.

Comment: but I can say that he is angry and it's only at the moment, right?

Comment: Yes, it is at that moment. If you want to indicate an instance of always, then you the word _always_. _He is always angry._ You can even consider saying _He has anger issues._ But it would certainly add many unwanted attributions to the context.

Comment: so then isn't it the same thing with sulky isn't it only at the moment? And when should I use the adjective with being?

Comment: You can't raise a grammar fight from isolated examples. You need context.

Comment: @coolguy Every word doesn't have a separate adjective and gerund form. You need to frame your sentences properly to convey the exact intended meaning.

Comment: One difference is that **anger** is a transitive verb, and **sulk** is intransitive.

Comment: I know but sulky isn't a verb, so with what adjectives am I saying that the person is always that and with what adjectives am I saying that the person is being like that at the moment without using being? is there a list?

Comment: I don't know why the title of your question is 'gerund vs adjective'. "Sulking" is not a gerund, but a present participle.

Comment: See [Present participle or adjective in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162934/present-participle-or-adjective-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

I'm "sulking": is a verb, you are describing what you are doing, whereas, I'm "sulky": is an adjective, you are describing yourself.